# How to check row is exist ? and fetch it for two table?

Tags: mysql

I have two table: `votes` | `favorites`.

Here is my structure:

```
// votes                                    // favorite
+----+---------+---------+-------+          +----+---------+---------+
| id | id_post | id_user | value |          | id | id_post | id_user |
+----+---------+---------+-------+          +----+---------+---------+
```

When I show a post, I need to know current user gave a vote to this post already or not, if yes, what is its value *(1 or -1)*? Also I need to check this post is favorite for current user or not ? So how can I implement it ?

My try:

for checking existing favorite:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM favorites WHERE post_id={} and user_id={} LIMIT 1) as favorite
```

Also I have the same query for checking there is any vote or not ? But I want to know how can both check and fetch ? And I want to know for mixing two query should I use of `join` ?

---

**Edit:**

Also here is the structure of `posts` table:

```
// posts
+----+-------+---------+----+-------------+-----------------+
| id | title | content | by | total_votes | total_favorites |
+----+-------+---------+----+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please also post the structure of the post table. This should be achievable with one query using joins.

Comment: I have tow column in `posts` table named `total_votes`, `total_favorites` and I update them via trigger *(after insert in `votes` or favorite table)*, anyway I think `posts` tables needs separated query.

Comment: But I am wondering about a column like `posts.id` relating it to the other tables. Do you posts to display for the user? It should be possible to get all this information in one query using left joins.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski please check out my update. I need to : `title`, `content`, `by`, `total_votes`, `total_favorites`, `there is any rows marked as favorite by user`, `there is any vote by user? what is its value ?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than querying separately to determine whether the current user has voted/favorited after already querying and fetching the posts, you can significantly reduce the number of queries overall by adding `LEFT JOIN`s to the query retrieving posts.

```
SELECT
  `posts`.`id`,
  `title`,
  `content`,
  `by`,
  `total_votes`,
  `total_favorites`,
  -- Use a CASE condition to return a value for votes
  -- based on whether a row is returned by the LEFT JOIN
  -- Change the values like 'has voted' to whatever you want them to be
  CASE 
    WHEN `votes`.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN 'has voted'
    ELSE 'has not voted'
  END AS `user_has_voted`,
  -- Also return the vote value, which will be NULL if no vote exists
  `votes`.`value` AS `vote_value`,
  -- Do the same for favorites
  CASE 
    WHEN `favorites`.`id` IS NOT NULL THEN 'has favorited'
    ELSE 'has not favorited'
  END AS `user_has_favorited`
FROM
  `posts`
  -- Supply the user's id to the ON condition
  -- for both of the joins.
  LEFT JOIN `votes`
    ON `posts`.`id` = `votes`.`id_post`
    AND `votes`.`id_user` = <user_id>
  LEFT JOIN `favorites`
    ON `posts`.`id` = `favorites`.`id_post`
    AND `favorites`.`id_user` = <user_id>
```

Doing it this way will accomplish everything in only one query.  The idea in using a `LEFT JOIN` is that it will return values from the related table if present, and otherwise return `NULL`. So in the `CASE` statement, you may check for `IS NOT NULL` to determine whether the vote/favorite exists.

Comment: what a clear and powerful answer, thanks, just onething: what is mean of this: `WHEN favorites.id IS NOT NULL` ? `vote.id` should be identical with `post.id`

Comment: @Sajad The `LEFT JOIN` will return the matching row if it is present, but if it is not, _all_ columns from the votes or favorites table will return `NULL`. So this condition tests for a `NULL` value returned by the join in the `id` column to determine if a row exists. It could also have been `WHEN favorites.id_post IS NOT NULL`. It does not really matter which column you use.

Comment: @Sajad Anyway, I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but please can you tell me your query is faster or using of two separated query (without `join`, because I think `join` is slow),  one query for fetching `posts` table, and one query for existing and fetching favorite and vote value ?

Comment: This should be much faster than using separate queries. But to take advantage of that, you should be sure you have created the correct foreign key constraints on the votes,favorites tables. Like `FOREIGN KEY (id_post) REFERENCES posts (id)`  With the indexes in place, it should be remarkably faster.

Comment: aha, but I use of MyISAM and unfortunately it does not support FK, So ? still can I use of your query ?

Comment: @Sajad For MyISAM, it should still take advantage of indexes even if it cannot enforce foreign key constraints. So instead you may index them as `ALTER TABLE votes ADD INDEX (id_post)`.  You may also need to index `id_user` using the composite `ALTER TABLE votes ADD INDEX (id_post, id_user)`..  The query optimizer should attempt to use the index when performing the JOIN.

Comment: oh, really sorry for asking again, that is the last: finally I create separated index for each column or composite? `ALTER TABLE votes ADD INDEX (id_post)` (and the same for `id_user`) OR `ALTER TABLE votes ADD INDEX (id_post, id_user)` ?

Comment: @Sajad I am not sure which will be better. You would need to check the `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for the query to see if it uses the composite index correctly. I think it would.

Comment: One consultation: is it better to I create two columns in the `Posts` table named `total_votes` and `total_favorites` and then update them via trigger after inserting in the `Votes`,`Favorites` tables OR do I use of `SUM()` for each request and calculate the number of total ?

Comment: Querying for the `SUM()` is much more complex. Updating them with a trigger will always allow your queries to run faster, so I would probably keep it as you have with the trigger. Otherwise I might consider creating a temporary table populated by querying the SUM() for each post to prevent having to retrieve the SUM() in real time, but the trigger is easier.

Comment: I found a new problem related to this question. look, As you know, I use `TRIGGER` for updating *total_votes* and *total_favorites* columns. there is a problem, when a user removes his account, all his votes will be remove, but still total vote is fixed. So I need to use of `SUM()` instead of total_votes and total_favorites columns. do you know how should I add `sum()` for counting the number of all votes and all favorites (from votes table and favorites table) in the the above code ?

Comment: @Sajad This should probably be asked as a new question. I would probably add a trigger on delete from the votes,favorites tables to subtract from total_votes,total_favorites. But to do a live query with SUM(), add `LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_post, COUNT(*) AS total_votes FROM votes GROUP BY id_post) total_votes ON posts.id = total_votes.id_post` And then add `total_votes.total_votes` to `SELECT`. This cannot be as fast as the trigger-updated columns though.

Comment: aha, but I think if I just add `sum(votes.value) as total_votes` in the `select`, it is fine, is it not ? (because I used of `left join` for `votes` table)

Comment: @Sajad I would think not, because of the `user_id` in the left join's `ON`. I would expect that to return NULL if the user had not voted rather than the SUM()

Comment: Oh Oh Oh ! the difference is very much. For your information, In reality: **TRIGGER:** 0,006 - **SUM(*):** 0,04 ! The waste time for each request: `0.034`. So trigger is much better.

Comment: Please take a look at your comment (four-to-last) and tell me your solution is better or this: add `LEFT JOIN votes total_votes ON posts.id = total_votes.id_post` and then add `SUM(total_votes.value)` to `SELECT` ?

Comment: @Sajad If you get the same result reliably, then your simpler join is maybe faster.

Comment: You are right, I don't get the same result, I was wring. Just your query returns correct result. Also I asked a new question (for comparing two query) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649019/using-sum-in-the-select-is-better-or-in-the-sub-select) and there is a great answer. If you like, you can check it. anyway thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
SELECT value 
FROM votes 
WHERE 
    id_post={@pid} AND
    id_user={@uid}
```

Will give you (If the database is consistent) 0 or 1 row(s) containing the value.

On DBClient side you can check if the resultset is empty or not, which is an implicit check for vote existence.

To fetch post and votes simultaneously this should work (Uodate: Incorporating the favorites):

```
SELECT p.*, v.value
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN votes v
    ON v.id_post = p.id
LEFT JOIN favorites f
    ON f.id_post = p.id
WHERE 
    p.id={@pid} AND
    v.id_user={@uid} AND
    f.id_user={@uid}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    p.id_post,
    if(f.favorite is null, 'No', 'Yes') favorite,
    if(v.vote is null, 0, v.vote) vote
from
    posts p
        left join
    (select 
        id_post, id_post favorite
    from
        favorites
    where
        id_user = 100 and id_post = 4) f ON (p.id_post = f.id_post)
        left join
    (select 
        id_post, value vote
    from
        votes
    where
        id_user = 100 and id_post = 4) v ON (p.id_post = v.id_post)
where
    p.id_post = 4;
```

replace the id_post = 4 and the id_user = 100
when vote is 0 means that the user has not yet rated